# Data Format String Display To Grid

Tags: c#, telerik, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have a field in sql that is Decimal(18,2) . I have already make my text box to insert numbers from 0 to 10 with 2 digits after comma and DecimalSeparator","

for example i insert 7,77 In SQL shown this as 777.00 i want to display it on grid as 7,77.

Any Help ?

Comment: check your column type, use DataFormatString property in your column, check the culture properties of the grid.

Comment: Already Use DataFormatString="{00000:0,00}" and display 777.00 as 777 but i want to move comma 2 positions left to show this as 7,77 is that possible ? I cant undestard how dataformatstring works exactyly

Comment: DataFormatstring is always relative to the culture. But when you say 7,77 is in sql you mean 777 or 7.77 . With The "."  as localized decimal separator?

Comment: here the documentation about Format string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_0

Comment: And btw In order string format to be applied the data should be of the correct type. So apply the correct type to the column with DataType